# Is it possible to release memory before starting an Activity?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have an activity that some times OutOfMemory exception occurs in some parts of it when data is large. It occurs some times in decryption. Some times in decompress and some times in calling web service method.

Is it possible to release Activity's memory or application's memory before doing my operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using bitmaps, you can recycle them. Set objects to null, so the chance they get recycled is larger. Try and call System.gc() . All these methods might result in freeing up some memory. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you mean by "release"ing an "Activity's memory", but the answer is probably no.  Instead if you are using bitmaps for instance you should be displaying them efficiently.  Check out [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from Google on how to display bitmaps efficiently.